# How to access pytorch model parameters by index

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

If I have network with let's say 10 layers including biases, how can I access its i'th layer parameters just by index?

Currently, what I am doing is something like this

```
for parameter in myModel.parameters():
    parameter.data /= 5
```

How could I access parameter.data with an index? For example I'd like to access 9th layer without iterating, such as myModel.parameter.data[8] or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply do a :

```
list(myModel.parameters())
```

Now it will be a list of weights and biases, in order to access weights of the first layer you can do:

```
print(layers[0])
```

in order to access biases of the first layer:

```
print(layers[1])
```

and so on.

Remember if bias is false for any particular layer it will have no entries at all, so for example if bias is false for second layer, then `layers[3]` will actually give weights of the third layer.

Comment: use `list(myModel.parameters())` instead of `[x.data for x in myModel.parameters()]`

Comment: @damavrom thanks for the suggestion that is a good suggestion, can u pl make the edit in this answer I will approve it so u can get the credits?

Thanks